# Why does autocompletion not work when typing a command name after `source`

Tags: bash

`source` searches `PATH` by default.

But in bash, autocompletion doesn't work when typing a command name after `source`.

In general, when does autocompletion based on `PATH` work, and when  does it not?

How can I make it work when typing the argument to  `source`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`source` (the `bash` builtin command) takes a **filename** argument; the PATH search is triggered only if the specified filename is not found.  So `source foo` tries first to open `./foo` and only when that fails does it go looking for `/path/dir/foo`.  Try tab-completion with filenames that exist in your current directory, or provide paths to the command you're interested in.  Those should tab-complete as you'd expect.

- The easiest way to achieve what you want is to recognize that tab-completion is attempting **complete-filename** but you want **complete-command**.  You can trigger **complete-command** with the `M-!` keybind aka <kbd>Alt+!</kbd>.  (See the `READLINE` section, `Completing` subsection, in `man bash` and in [bash online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html#Commands-For-Completion) for other completion functions and default keybinds.)
- The hard way would be to revise the default completion functions triggered for `source`'s first argument to call both the **complete-filename** and **complete-command** functions.  See `help complete` (on your commandline), the `Programmable Completion` subsection in `man bash` and in [bash online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion), and the `complete` builtin command.

In general, tab-completion is positional, and calls different completion functions based on where you are in the commandline.  On Arch systems, packages can install a completion file into `/usr/share/bash-completion` to provide context-aware completions for their executables.

Comment: (the *other* easy way is to start your command *without* `source` -- so tab-completion lets you complete the command -- then press `Home` to return to the start of the commandline -- then enter `source ` (or `. `) before the command.)